# Nuxt3 data fetching not working after client-side navigation

Tags: nuxtjs3

I am working on a Nuxt3 app locally. I have a page component `[slug].vue` page component for blog posts which fetches data from a Strapi endpoint. When I navigate from the home page to a blog post via `<nuxt-link>` I get an empty page. When I reload the page in the browser, the data gets displayed. At this point I am kinda lost and don't know what's wrong. Here is the code of the `[slug].vue`

```
<template>
  <section id="start" class="min-h-screen flex items-center">
    <LayoutMoContainer is-narrow>
      <div v-if="pending">
        Loading ...
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <div v-if="post">
          <AtomsMoHeadline v-if="post.title" class="text-center" headline-type="h1" :text="post.title" />
          <div v-if="post.content" class="dark:text-white">
            <div v-html="post.content"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </LayoutMoContainer>
  </section>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
/**
 * Fetch posts
 */

const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const STRAPI_URL = config.STRAPI_URL;
const route = useRoute();
const slug = route.params.slug;
const { pending, data: post } = await useLazyAsyncData('post', () => $fetch(`${STRAPI_URL}articles/${slug}`), { server: false });

</script>
```

Nuxt Project Info

```
- Operating System: `Darwin`
- Node Version:     `v18.7.0`
- Nuxt Version:     `3.0.0-rc.6`
- Package Manager:  `yarn@1.22.19`
- Builder:          `vite`
- User Config:      `publicRuntimeConfig`, `app`, `css`, `buildModules`, `build`, `vite`
- Runtime Modules:  `-`
- Build Modules:    `@pinia/nuxt@0.3.1`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was due to a page component having more than one root element.